# Add Call Extension to Search Ads based on API call

Tags: google-ads-api

[image]

I am making click to call based ad which you might see in the above example image. What I want to achieve is that I want to show that number dynamically, meaning that when the call representative is available it shows in the ad but when the representative is not available then the ad wouldn't show the click to call button.

To clear this more: I want to make an API call to the server which will tell me if any representative is available or not.

I am using JavaScript for my front-end and back-end, so let me know if I can do it using that or any other suggestions are welcome too.

What I have done so far:
As per my research I can not this, but I may be wrong and that's why I am posting a question here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possible.

If you have clear working hours for callcenters then you can schedule ad with and without `Call Extension` ads based on that.

[image]

Reference : [Create an ad schedule](https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/6372656)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, where to add scripts for your campaigns.

Comment: @ImmadHamid No it's not script it is targeting for Campaign or AdGroup where you can set time for which your ad can be visible/served to users.